# How to refer to changing data in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

can you please help me maybe with basic question about refering to changing data in excel on the other sheet?
The thing is: I have a vlookup in Sheet 2 and in the Sheet 1 I import data from txt.

For every new instance I delete data in Sheet 1 and import new data to the same sheet. 
After I do this - Excel stops to work and shows error in reference, because the data is previous data is missing.
But I want to preserve the same references such as A1, B2, etc. together with new imported data.

Thank you for your help.
Barbora

Comment: Sorry, for misunderstanding - I only clear it. Butthe references are not kept.

Comment: gotcha, do you delete rows / columns? or only cell contents? are you using VBA?

Comment: Well, I delete them and the import another data. Do you think that only emptying them would help?

Comment: for sure, that would not create #REF

Comment: Yes! it helped! Thank you, I knew it would be a tricky small bastard :D Thanky you a lot!

Comment: cheers! glad to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid creating reference errors, clear the contents of the cells, rather than deleting the actual rows, columns, and / or cells...